# SQL table implementation

Tags: sql

[image: ER model]

I need to implement these two entities(paper & reviewers) from the model that are connected via a many to many (m:n) relationship and show how these two entities and the relationship between them would be implemented as SQL tables. The answer should be in the form of create table statements: I should include as many tables as you need to implement the chosen entities and their relationship. Can please someone help.
I've done that so far:

```
create table reviewer(
rreviewer_email varchar(15);
rreviewer_specification varchar(30);
rreviewer_name varchar(20);)

create table paper(
ppaper_title varchar(20);
ppaper_ID varchar(15);
ppaper_rating varchar(10);
ppaper_set_of_keys varchar(30);

constraintt FK rreviewer_name REFERENCES ppaper_title;
```

Comment: I don't understand your question. Your SQL here above contains several errors.

Comment: I don't understand which two attributes should I reference to each other in order to create the third table

Comment: Your third table would include the Primary Keys of both these tables, i.e. ppaper_ID, rreviewer_name.

Comment: You probably need a table called something like `ReviewerPaper` that links to both tables.

Comment: is that right

`create table ReviewerPaper
(
rrewiewer_email varchar2(15) NOT NULL;
ppaper_ID int NOT NULL;
CONSTRAINT FK_ReviewerPaper PRIMARY KEY
(
 rreviewer_email,
 ppaper_ID
),
    FOREIGN KEY (rreviewer_email) REFERENCES reviewer (rreviewer_email),
    FOREIGN KEY (ppaper_ID) REFERENCES paper (ppaper_ID)
)`

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: why do you start all your column names with two rrs or two pps? You need to include primary keys in your reviewer and paper tables (you shouldn't use email for that). Is this homework?